# I'm trying to setup showoff.io or localtunnel on a Mac, but I'm stuck

Tags: bash, terminal, tunnel

I installed the gem according to the instructions at [showoff.io](https://showoff.io/), but when I try to run

```
show 8888
```

it doesn't work and I get

```
-bash: show: command not found
```

In their [faq](https://showoff.io/support#faq), they mention running

```
gem contents showoff-io
```

if that happens, but I don't know how to read what I get:

```
Rakefile
Gemfile
lib/showoff/client.rb
lib/showoff/settings.rb
lib/showoff/api.rb
lib/showoff/helpers.rb
lib/showoff/version.rb
lib/showoff/setup.rb
lib/showoff/session.rb
lib/showoff.rb
bin/show
```

They say this:

> This will list all of the files in the showoff-io gem. Look for the bin/show script. Either add that folder to your $PATH, or symlink the script into a location already on your $PATH. For example:

```
sudo ln -s /var/ruby/gems/.../bin/show /usr/local/bin
```

But obviously copy&pasting that doesn't do anything because those are just example paths.

I'm sure this is very basic, but I'm a novice at this. What do I have to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following command to determine the directory that gem installs executable files in and then add it to you PATH.

```
gem env | grep "EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY"
```

Alternatively you can run the following command which will symlink the show command into your /usr/bin directory

```
sudo ln -s $(gem env | grep "EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY" | cut -d":" -f 2)/show /usr/bin/show
```

Comment: I'm a newbie and I don't know what to put in EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Its not a place holder, you should be able to copy and paste either of those commands into a terminal without modifying them at all.